# How to bake a roughness map from a sculpted mesh in Blender 2.8?

Tags: texture-baking, roughness

I selected the option to bake the roughness map, but the bake doesn't register anything. I just get a grey image with no detail on it. I baked normals, AO and discplacement and these are all fine, why not the roughness map?

Comment: Roughness depends on the material. It's not only a geometry parameter.

Comment: roughness for a character is usually done by texture painting.

Comment: Not really. You can easily do this in Zbrush and Substance Painter. Why not in blender?